# Asking questions about Bollywood movies

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions about Bollywood (Indian) movies, in private beta? Or is it inappropriate as private beta has few users?

Comment: They *are* movies, aren't they?

Comment: @Alexei  Of Course they are movies, Got the point :)

Comment: Well I guess asking questions about any movie of any language is allowed

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As long as the question is good, I think it is okay. I am pretty sure a few of us know some Bollywood movies as well. If not we can always invite an expert into private beta.